# Tree decomposition for planar graphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, treewidth, integer-lattice

First asked on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10944/tree-decomposition-for-planar-nearest-neighbor-graphs) with no replies.

1. Suppose I have a planar graph, with a planar embedding, how do I find tree decomposition?
2. What is the optimal tree decomposition of a $d$-by-$d$ square grid? Not completely sure how to define "optimal", but it should distinguish between decomposition with one large bag and decomposition with many large bags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If what you really want is a good elimination order, you might be looking for [generalized nested dissection](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2156840).  This is the strategy that exploits the good separators of a planar graph to give $O(n^{\omega/2})$ algorithms for Gaussian elimination, determinant, etc. for matrices coming from planar graphs.

Comment: Interesting, I found a whole trove of literature expanding on the method. If I understand correctly, given optimal elimination order, optimal tree decomposition is easy

Answer (score 14):

For the first question, it is *open* whether finding a tree decomposition for planar graphs can be done in polynomial time. The best approximation algorithm may be the [**RatCatcher**](http://www.springerlink.com/content/q6vh7756761j1m70/) algorithm by Seymour and Thomas, which computes the *branchwidth* of the planar graph, so it has a 1.5 approximation ratio by the relation between branchwidth and treewidth.

For the second one, we have the following theorem about the treewidth of $k \times k$ grids:

> **Theorem.** A $k \times k$ grid has treewidth $k$.

And the bags can be taken with size $k+1$, with a total $k(k-1)$ bags. I'm not sure if this is what you want, so feel free to do it if you modify the definition of "optimal".

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want an optimal tree decomposition, you can build a tree decomposition by computing separators recursively.